# Forecast/predict commodity prices

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models

I search for a way to model future commodity prices, like heating oil and natural gas. It doesn't have to be very sophisticated, but rather easily to implement.

Does anybody know a suitable approach? After theoretical examination, I plan to apply it to real data in R. Thus, implentation in a R package would be good.

Thank you!

Comment: This is much too broad for us to give a (conclusive) answer. Could you trim it down a bit, _e.g._ tell us more about your theoretical examination?

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated, more detail on your study would be helpful.

With that being said, commodity prices (in general) tend to show more stationarity on the whole than other assets such as stocks or currencies, i.e. with commodity prices, there tends to be less of a trend and more of a zigzag pattern.

In this regard, you should test your data for stationarity using a stationarity test such as Dickey-Fuller or Phillips-Perron.

Then, a commonly used tool to implement time series forecasting of such models would be ARCH models (Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity). These could be run in R using libraries such as rugarch or fGarch.

You might find the following [paper](http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/206582/2/5-A-Lama.pdf) helpful - EGarch models in particular (exponential GARCH) was found to be superior to ARIMA and GARCH models in forecasting international cotton prices given the ability of such a model to capture asymmetric volatility patterns.

Again, all depends on your data, but the above might be helpful as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks so far. My goal is to predict energy savings from some efficiency measure. First step would be finding factors that influence the outcome, namely energy savings. E.g. commodity price, like heating oil or gas price, outdoor temperature which influences energy load directly and lets say maintenance cost. Therefore I need to predict all of those factors x-times separately in order to get their distributions and apply Monte Carlo Simulation in the next step to get the distribution of my final outcome variable, energy savings.

Comment: .....I will probably use seasonal ARIMA for the temperature and a Fourier Series approach for the energy load, but I'm really struggling to find an appropriate model/approach for commodity prices.

Comment: If you're looking to predict energy savings through various explanatory variables, then you're likely better off using a regression analysis in this scenario. You can certainly run a Monte Carlo simulation - a logistic regression (if your variables were categorical) would allow to determine probability of energy savings based on the parameters of your explanatory variables.

Comment: Well, the concept of dertermining the distribution of the explanatory variables first, followed by MC is actually set. So in this case, EGARCH or GARCH would be the way to go?

Comment: Well, you could always run a simplified GARCH model, and then see if variants such as EGARCH provide a better forecast.